# Part of the page loaded with ajax. Problem with scroll position

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of problem with ajax on my web app.
Part of my website is loaded with the ajax method. Header and Footer loaded a static.

When I back to my previous page (button in browser) or refresh page (F5), my web application doesn't remember my scrolltop position (page height increases after loading) so almost every time it scrolls to the bottom of Footer.

I came up with a solution in javascript. My plugin saved a scrollTop position after click, and after loaded the page, it check it, if scrollTop is save:

```
$.plugin('scrollRestoration', {

        init: function () {
            var me = this;
            me.registerEvents();
            me.scrollRestorationLoad();
        },

        registerEvents: function () {
            var me = this;
            me._on(window, 'click', $.proxy(me.scrollRestorationSave, me));
        },

        scrollRestorationSave: function () {
            sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', $(window).scrollTop());
            console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
        },

        scrollRestorationLoad: function () {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') != null) {

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
                    console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
                }, 2000);
            }

            else {
                $(window).scrollTop(0);
                console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
            }
        },
    });
```

but I'm not entirely happy with this solution, because it loads only after 2sec (after loading the ajax page)

Comment: You set a timeout of 2 seconds for it to load, I assume you realise this? If you just want it to wait for the ajax to load, you could make it rely on the ajax's Promise being resolved. But I don't know how easy that is, since you haven't shown the code which does that part.

Comment: @ADyson, yes. I know. If time of the loaded ajax exceeds 2sec, my plugin doesn't work :f

Comment: That's why you need to tell your code to wait for the AJAX to complete, rather than just setting a timer.

Comment: @ADyson, I can't use this code, because my web app use more ajax method. :-(

Comment: In that case you have to tie it directly to the outcome of the specific ajax call that's causing the problem. How and where is this ajax call made in your code?